# Rubymine editing an External Library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rubymine

I need to edit a gem(Devise) in order to understand where exactly a particular error occurs, so I need to put a "logger.debug" after every variable. 
Problem is, I cannot edit any of the Gems, as they appear locked in Rubymine under 'external libraries".
Is there an easy way to do what I am trying to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Open the file, attempt to edit it, and you should see the following pop-up:

[image]

Choose the appropriate option, click "OK", and edit away.